# Concept of performing a t-test while controlling/adjusting for one or more variables?

Tags: t-test, linear-model, predictor, adjustment

Could someone please help me understand the concept of performing a t-test while controlling/adjusting for one or more variables?

E.g.: Say I have a hypothetical data set, with the following variables `sex, age, smoker, weight, height, bmi, smoking_duration, max_oxygen_uptake`. Let us say I want to test if smokers have a higher `max_oxygen_uptake`, than non-smokers?

Then in R I would write: `t.test(subset(myData,myData$smoker==0)$max_oxygen_uptake,subset(myData,myData$smoker==1)$max_oxygen_uptake)`

But `max_oxygen_uptake` will likely also depend on e.g. `age`, `bmi` and `smoking_duration`. Maybe also `sex`. Therefore I am looking for something along the lines of: `t.test(var_a,var_b,adjust=c(var_c,var_d,var_e))`.

Questions:

1. How do I perform a t-test, while controlling/adjusting for other variables?
2. How do I decide which variables should be controlled/adjusted for?

I know it has something to do with `lm()`, but I am having conceptual problems in connecting the t-test to creating a linear model?